# Get count of current div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I used the jquery to get count is

```
var currentPosition = 0;
var slides = $(".slideritem");
var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

manageControls(currentPosition);
function manageControls(position){
var count = document.getElementById("count");
count.innerHTML =(position + 1) + "/" + numberOfSlides;
  }
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshmonster/ZUZXg/2/). It shows the count but it doesn't update when i go to next div. Any solution ?

Comment: your fiddle works for me, but looks nothing like the code posted here

Comment: who dosen't update i can't see your problem i guess your code is working fine

Comment: forgot to update JSFiddle. Try it now. When you click the next, it doesn't show the count as 2/3.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a call to `manageControls()`... You can place it here:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    setActive(index);
    manageControls(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentPosition = 0;
 var slides = $(".myclass");
 var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

 manageControls(currentPosition);
 function manageControls(position){
 var count = document.getElementById("count");
 count.innerHTML =(position + 1) + "/" + numberOfSlides;
 }

 setActive(0);

$('li').click(function() {
setActive($(this).index());
manageControls($(this).index());

});

  $(".next").click(function(){
   var current = $('ul li.selected').index(),
    maxIndex = $('ul li').length - 1,
    next = (current + 1) >  maxIndex ? 0 : (current + 1);
   manageControls(next);
   setActive(next);

  });

 function setActive(i) {
var li = $('ul li').eq(i);

$('ul li').removeClass('selected');
li.addClass('selected');
$('.myclass').removeClass('selected');
$('.myclass').eq(i).addClass('selected');
 }
```

Comment: Work perfect. Thanks for your answers Sora. :)